# This code, why does it have to show undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

According to this sentence in [[lex.phases]1.2](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.phases#1.2)

> Except for splices reverted in a raw string literal, if a splice
>   results in a character sequence that matches the syntax of a
>   universal-character-name, the behavior is undefined.

the snippet below has undefined behavior ([live-example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d02251c2e8657699)):

```
#include <iostream>

// According to [lex.phases]1.2 this has undefined behavior

const char* p = "\\
u0041";

int main()
{
    std::cout << p << '\n';
}
```

What's the reason for the undefined behavior?

Answer (score 8):

See the discussion in [core issue 787](https://wg21.link/cwg787):

> The undefined behavior referred to above regarding
>   *universal-character-name*s is the result of the considerations
>   described in the C99 Rationale, section 5.2.1, in the part entitled
>   “UCN models.” Three different models for support of UCNs are
>   described, each involving different conversions between UCNs and wide
>   characters and/or at different times during program translation.
>   Implementations, as well as the specification in a language standard,
>   can employ any of the three, but it must be impossible for a
>   well-defined program to determine which model was actually employed by
>   implementation. The implication of this “equivalence principle” is
>   that any construct that would give different results under the
>   different models must be classified as undefined behavior. For
>   example, an apparent UCN resulting from a line-splice would be
>   recognized as a UCN by an implementation in which all wide characters
>   were translated immediately into UCNs, as described in C++ phase 1,
>   but would not be recognized as a UCN by another implementation in
>   which all UCNs were translated immediately into wide characters (a
>   possibility mentioned parenthetically in C++ phase 1).

Comment: `... , but would not be recognized as a UCN by another implementation in which all UCNs were translated immediately into wide characters (a possibility mentioned parenthetically in C++ phase 1)`. I just can't find this possibility being mentioned in C++ Translation Phase 1. Could you explore this?

Comment: @Alexander "An implementation may use any internal encoding, so long as an actual extended character encountered in the source file, and the same extended character expressed in the source file as a universal-character-name (i.e., using the \uXXXX notation), are handled equivalently except where this replacement is reverted in a raw string literal."

Comment: I found this line interesting: *The implication of this “equivalence principle” is that any construct that would give different results under the different models must be classified as undefined behavior.*  Is the intention that if the Standard would allow any combination of two or more behaviors that can't reliably be distinguished, it must allow arbitrary behavior even in cases where all possible combinations of the *described* behaviors would have met a program's requirements?  Or is the intention that implementations should do whatever makes sense for their means of translation?

Comment: @T.C. I have no problem with the text you've just quoted above from [lex.phases]/1.1, as this in accordance with the following words in the Deffect Report: `For example, an apparent UCN resulting from a line-splice would be recognized as a UCN by an implementation in which all wide characters were translated immediately into UCNs, as described in C++ phase 1, ...`. (to be continued).

Comment: @T.C.  My problem was with the second part of this comment in the DR, `..., but would not be recognized as UCN by another implementation in which all UCNs were translated immediately into wide characters (a possibility mentioned parenthetically in C++ phase 1)`. What I'm saying is that, as far as I can understand [lex.phases]/1.1 doesn't say anything about this last part.

Comment: @Alexander "An implementation may use **any internal encoding**". **any**. Including one in which the internal encoding is wide characters rather than UCNs.

Comment: @T.C. That's exactly the case treated in the first part of the sentence, when the implementation translates multibyte characters (internal encoding) into UCN's. What I'm saying is that [lex.phases]1.1 doesn't say anything about the possibility of a translation from UCNs to multibyte characters (wide characters), as described in the second part of the text in the DR.

Comment: @T.C. If we assume that the Standard doesn't say anything about this second part of the text in the DR, than, there is no reason for the undefined behavior mentioned in [lex.phases]/1.2.

Comment: @Alexander "Internal encoding" means the representation internally used by the implementation. Which can be wide characters (in which case the implementation immediately translates any UCNs it encounter into wide characters), or can be UCNs (in which case the implementation immediate translates any wide character it encounters into UCNs), because the standard says it can use *any* internal encoding.

Comment: In any event, it doesn't matter. As-if applies, and the UB exists precisely to give implementations leeway to use any of the three models in the C99 rationale, whether the standard text explicitly mention such models or not.